# Error occurs in configuring project:app when I am using any project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, projects-and-solutions

I'm facing weird issue on my android studio.

Whenever I'm running any project on my android studio I'm getting below error.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'
Could not download hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3): No cached version available for offline mode
```

If anyone has idea or has faced this issue then please provide me solution so that how can I solve above this problem.

Comment: are you setting gredle settings to work offline ?

Comment: No, how can i see that my gredle setting is offline or online ?

Comment: check File->Settings->Gradle->Global Gradle Settings and give me a feedback if it works

Comment: Was the wrong with the offline gradle option?

Comment: 'Hey, I am done it.error was in Path of gradle not in mode of gradle. And thanks for suggesting the Idea to check gradle setting.' @DasserBasyouni

Comment: 'I don't know but i change my first path and clean the project than again paste same older path and rebuild the project. So it's work.'@DasserBasyouni

Comment: your very wellcome, you may post your answer to you question then, and if anything went wrong again ask me if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Not depending on cache files but same project you are running on different devices and for that it will not working some time in your Laptop/PC.

but We need to refresh path of **gradle** by doing some changes like change path or directory from `setting>gradle>gradle_path` and also store old path at any location but safe place, because you will need it further.

Now refresh or rebuild your project it will gives error same as first you seen but when you set same path which was first when you change. now rebuild project again it will works properly.